# Testing the linearity of a CMOS image sensor

Tags: image-sensor

The EMVA 1288 standard guides how to measure the linearity of a digital image sensor, i.e., if the digital number from a pixel changes linearly to the incident light intensity. The procedure includes a measurement of the incident light intensity, which requires a separate light detector from the image sensor. However, I thought that one can simply determine the linearity by fixing the light intensity and all other settings and by adjusting the exposure time. If the pixel response is linear with respect to the exposure time, the all of the conversions (1)-(4) should be linear. Am I missing something?

(1) conversion of photons to photoelectrons

(2) conversion of photoelectrons to a voltage (by a capacitor)

(3) amplification of the voltage

(4) conversion of the voltage to a digital number

Comment: Your previous question was how to measure nonlinearity using EMVA1288 (which typically assumes a linear model), but your new question asks how to decide when a linear model is appropriate.  These are completely different questions, and all four of the previous answers are now answering the wrong question.  It probably would have been better to mark this one as answered and then post a new topic for the new question.

Comment: @user1850479 I rollbacked the question to the original one and selected one answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could work if the exposure time is linear, but it may not be, it depends on how the gating of the timer works. But in the end you'll be testing the linearity of exposure timing and how well that works. I would think that you would want that variable to be fixed and adjust the actual photons going into the device instead of changing how you measure the photons.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The exposure time can be independently measured by blinking LEDs or similar ways. It would be reasonably easy to crosscheck if 10 ms, 100 ms, 1 s, 5 s, 10 s are accurately set.

Comment: I'd expect the exposure time to be linear when well above the minimum, but for linearity to break down at the highest speeds.  This can be improved somewhat by software that only allows realistic increments. For example: 10µs minimum exposure, clocked in 2.5µs increments - good software won't allow you to specify 11µs, or will change your set value to one it can do.  Plenty of bad software will happily let you set 11µs but expose for 10, 12.5, or even sometimes one, sometimes the other.  In house test software using the API often fails to check true values, even if checking is supported.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that measuring linearity with respect to exposure time is the same as linearity with respect to intensity. For intensity, a photodetector will start to saturate and behave non-linearly as its voltage output approaches the bias voltage, which depends on the applied voltage and the load resistance (see [these](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Photodetector_Lab.pdf) experiments from Thorlabs). As for exposure time, the linearity will depend on the quantizer which  will saturate when it reaches its maximum integer size.

This is to say, you can saturate the detector at any exposure time with a sufficiently intense light source (e.g. pointing a strong laser right at the detector). Or you can saturate the ADC by applying a certain intensity, which may or may not be in the detector's linear range, for an amount of time that causes it to count up to its max value. I don't believe that there is an equivalency between these two things.

Comment: If we test the pixel value vs exposure time for different gain settings and constantly see that the relationship is linear as far as the pixel is not saturated, then wouldn't it be reasonable to conclude that the pixel response is linear with respect to the light intensity? For the purpose of this test, we can simply avoid the saturation by a reasonably small gain and light intensity, and by adjusting the exposure time within a range.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for the photon transfer curve. Janesick's book *Photon transfer : DN --> [lambda]* is the goto reference source for this. Search for *photon transfer curve*

Answer (score 1):

> However, I thought that one can simply determine the linearity by fixing the light intensity and all other settings and by adjusting the exposure time. If the pixel response is linear with respect to the exposure time, all of the conversions (1)-(4) should be linear. Am I missing something?

This is actually one of the methods described by the standard:

```
6.3 Variation of Irradiation
Basically, there are three possibilities to vary the radiant exposure of the sensor, i. e., the
radiation energy per area received by the image sensor:

I. Constant illumination with variable exposure time.
With this method, the light source is operated with constant radiance and the radiant
exposure is changed by the variation of the exposure time. The radiant exposure H
is given as the irradiance E times the exposure time texp of the camera. Because the
dark signal generally may depend on the exposure time, it is required to measure the
dark image at every exposure time used. The absolute calibration depends on the true
exposure time being equal to the exposure time set in the camera
```

https://www.emva.org/wp-content/uploads/EMVA1288Linear_4.0Release.pdf

So yes, that is a valid method in so much as you know the exposure time accurately, which is probably the case so long as the exposure times are relatively long and thus not seriously affected by quantization of clock cycles.  Note that you will still need some means of calibration (of DN to photons) to get absolute linearity (relative to number of photons).

Comment: Below the description, it is written that "According to basic assumptions number one and two made in Section 1.2, all three methods are equivalent ... ". The assumption number two is that the sensor is linear, which I want to confirm.

Comment: @Nownuri The conventional EMVA1288 model is linear, so if those assumptions do not hold you would have to use the new General model. However, they will hold for virtually any conventional CMOS image sensor. Usually it is not necessary to verify this unless you have invented some exotic new sensor.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tested OV5647 (in Raspberry Pi Camera v1) and saw that its pixel response is non-linear with respect to exposure time.

Comment: @Nownuri That's an ordinary CMOS sensor, so it's response will be linear with exposure time. If you're seeing significant deviation from linear, double check your configuration and data as something is wrong.